# Viewpager update and backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a view pager with 2 scrolling pages in my app. at first I populate it with two **fragments**.

In first **fragment** I have a button. clicking the button new adapter is created and  view pager is populated with two different fragments. at the moment when I press back I exit from the app instead I want to restore previous state of the view pager. please help

**For the first time:**

```
ViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),nBank);
                    mViewpager.invalidate();
                    mViewpager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```

**Second time:**

```
public void onListItemPressed(Currency objectCurrency) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DetailPagerAdapter detaluriadapteri = new DetailPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewpager.setAdapter(detaluriadapteri);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be to implement onBackPressed:

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mViewpager != null && mViewpager.getAdapter() instanceof DetailPagerAdapter) {
        ViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),nBank);
        mViewpager.invalidate();
        mViewpager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();  
    }
}
```

Though, I think it would be better to start a new activity using DetailPagerAdapter  when onListItemPressed is called. This way the default behavior of android would be to navigate back to your main activity on backpress, currently your main activity could be getting too much responsibility. Thus, having a self contained activity handling the details part would also be easier to maintain as it might need different tabs, actionbar menu items, etc..

Could also be a Fragment containing a the details viewpager but I have had trouble implementing this myself. Should be possible though and my trouble might be caused by some of the libraries I use.

Comment: I thought about the new activity, but the problem is a little bit complex. I use action bar navigation drawer and view pager in my single activity so using second Activity will cause some problems I guess.

Comment: Yeah ok, then stick with this for now. But perhaps give it a go at embedding the DetailPagerAdapter in it's own fragment if the activity code gets crowded at some point.